# Missing Reference when using the Excel Library with Microsoft visual studio 2012

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, excellibrary

I am using Visual studio 2012 with MySql database .. I am trying to generate simple report using Forms. When click on button the reports will generate in EXCEL sheet. The problem that I am facing is using this library:  `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`   when I used it says :     **One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?**
[image]

as shown in the figure  !!

Please Any Help ??
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have sort out the problem :)
 A default project in Visual Studio 2010 should have references to Microsoft.CSharp and System.Core.

In 2012, If they are not referenced in your project you need to add them, and the errors will go away.

Thanks